# Batch file for detecting USB Name

Tags: batch-file, usb, detect, xcopy, usb-drive

I need a batch script which detects a specific USB name and if that's found I want it to make a certain command like xcopy

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I searched here for another questions like mine and also found some good scripts but they didn't word

Comment: Good thst yoi tried sone solutions already. Can you post some code that you have tried, it will then be easier for folk here to help you fix it. Stack Overflow helps people with specific problems in their code, but not to provide complete chunks of code as ready made solutions. This encourages learning and problem solving. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code, providing that it runs with administrative privileges on Windows 7

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1*" %%a in ('fsutil fsinfo drives') do (
   for %%c in (%%b) do (
      for /F "tokens=3" %%d in ('fsutil fsinfo drivetype %%c') do (
         if %%d equ Removable (
            echo Drive %%c is Removable (USB^)
         )
      )
   )
)
```

Comment: You should note that this requires Administrative privileges on Windows 7.